# can I use the value of the arguments more than once

Tags: python, html, django

My problem is in python/django

I want to use the value of my argument `entry` before passing it on to my function util.get_entry

Below is my original code:

```
def display_entry(request, entry):
    entry = util.get_entry(entry)
    markdowner = Markdown()
    context = {'entry': markdowner.convert(entry)}
    return render(request, "my_app/entry.html", context)
```

I have tried to do:

```
def display_entry(request, entry):
    title = entry
    entry = util.get_entry(entry)
    markdowner = Markdown()
    context = {'entry': markdowner.convert(entry)}
    return render(request, "my_app/entry.html", context, title)
```

The goal is to be able to render the title of my page dynamically but it produces unexpected results.

I am sure it is something very simple but currently I am not seeing it.

Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: What do you mean by “title” here?

Comment: In my HTML page, I would use ```{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}```

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you're doing with the `Markdown` and `get_entry` stuff, but you can just add one line before your return like that `context.update({'title':entry})`.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, that was dead on. To clarify, util.get-entry is a view in my urls.py/urlpatterns.